# How do I convert a parameter of type "std::function" to a slightly different std::function?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a function, one of the parameters of which is of type `std::function<std::string(ConvertableToInt)>`, where "ConvertableToInt" is a type that can be converted to int *and can be constructed from int*. From this function, I need to call another (library) function one of the parameters of which is of type `std::function<std::string(int)>`.

Here is where the task arises. The library layer's function allows a callback to get a string from the application. The callback takes an index as a parameter. However, the application layer doesn't know these indices; it operates with wrapping objects that can be mapped to and constructed from an index. I want to write an intermediate function that helps to call the application callback.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The fact that the argument of the provided function is convertible to `int` is of no help - you need one that's constructible **from** `int`. Consider the direction of the data flow: that library you use is going to call your adapter and pass an `int` - that adapter then needs to somehow come up with an instance of the class to pass to the original function.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what your code structure and control flow is. Can you elaborate? Provide a minimal example and pin point *where* you'd like to call something? Describing code is a poor substitute for showing it.

Comment: Now, if that class is in fact constructible from `int`, then you can adapt it this way: `auto adapter = [originalFunction](int val) { return originalFunction(ConstructibleFromInt(val)); };` Now `adapter` can be used where `std::function<std::string(int)>` is needed.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The code doesn't exists yet; I just want to implement it. The library layer's function allows a callback to get a string from the application. The callback takes an index as a parameter. However, the application layer doesn't know these indices; it operates with wrapping objects that can be mapped to and constructed from an index. I want to write an intermediate function that helps to call the application callback.

Comment: The code doesn't have to be compile-able. Show us some pseudo code that you think elaborates your intention the best.

Comment: so you pass a callback to the library to give the library a way of getting a string from the application when the library wants one, but that callback takes an integer index, and you do not have indices you just have objects that know their index? I mean, then the application needs to maintain a table mapping indices to these objects.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It seems like your suggestion should work. I cannot test this yet, since an another person should write the actual application callback; but from general considerations, this is the correct solution. I missed the point that there should be construction, not conversion. So if you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to flesh out what Igor is saying in comments, if what you mean is that the class is constructible from an `int` then you can use a lambda as an adaptor as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

class constructible_from_int {
    int v_;
public:
    constructible_from_int(int v) : v_(v) {}
    int value() const { return v_; }
};

void call_a_func(int n, const std::function<std::string(int)>& func_that_takes_an_int) {
    std::cout << "value => " << func_that_takes_an_int(n) << "\n";
}

std::string func_that_takes_a_constructible_from_int(constructible_from_int cfi) {
    return std::to_string(cfi.value());
}

int main() {
    call_a_func(42,
        [](int v) { return func_that_takes_a_constructible_from_int(v); }
    );
}
```